# In a Emacs + Slime + Clojure + Windows setup, failure to load clojure-auto

Tags: windows, emacs, clojure, slime

I followed [this very helpful guide](http://dc.clj.fogus.me/index.php?title=Installing_Clojure_and_Slime_on_Windows) on getting this development environment set up. When running the *emacs.bat* I get the following error in Emacs:

> File error: Cannot open load file, clojure-auto

Unfortunitely I am completely new to both Clojure and Emacs, so any help in even figuring out where to begin looking would be helpful.

Also, as a side note the last step in the guide is:

> Start up Emacs using the emacs.bat file. Then, just type "M-x slime", and the REPL will come up, and you're on your way.

According to the Emacs documentation, M-x would be Meta key + x. It's unclear on the Meta key in Windows, however. It talks about Control, but that would be C+x, so I assume it's Shift. I also tried M+! thinking it was a shell command, but no luck. Perhaps somebody could confirm in a comment.

**Update:** From *dfa* in the comments: "meta is Alt" which works. Thank you.

**Update:** Very helpful info from Rayne:

> If you're emacs experience continues to go the wrong way, don't give up on Clojure. There is always La Clojure for IDEA Clojure-dev for Eclipse and my personal favorite, Enclojure for NetBeans.

Comment: If you're emacs experience continues to go the wrong way, don't give up on Clojure. There is always La Clojure for IDEA Clojure-dev for Eclipse and my personal favorite, Enclojure for NetBeans.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather than following the guide, why not just install [ClojureBox](http://clojure.bighugh.com/)?  That will set it all up for you.  It's a turnkey clojure + emacs installation.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is most likely in the load-path command where you tell it where the closure files are. Try expanding the path to be a full path name and see if that helps.

You could also try setting your HOME environment variable, I think the code there relies on it being C:\clojure-dev

Comment: The emacs.bat file automatically sets HOME to be the path you are running the batch file from. I ECHOed HOME and it was being properly set to my folder. Also, when I manually changed the user-home var in .emacs to something incorrect, I got a failout sooner (couldn't load Slime). In fact all of the load-path appears to be correct. My gut feeling is that a library was moved (clojure-auto?) in a newer version of one of these packages and one of the other ones hasn't updated its reference yet...

Comment: You can search the clojure folder from emacs using rgrep, as long as you have the gnu tools (find) installed. M-x rgrep then tell it the string you're looking for and the path to look in.

Answer (score 2):

I [documented](http://tommih.blogspot.com/2009/08/emacs-clojure-and-windows.html) my own experience in installing Emacs and the latest Clojure from Git repositories into Windows Vista. You might find it useful. 
If you're happy with Clojure 1.0.0 you can just install Clojure Box, though.