# loading slime on windows emacs

Tags: windows, emacs, slime

I tried to use slime on my Windows 7 box with a recent Emacs. I had problems giving the full path of the sbcl executable, as it had spaces in them. At last I have solved the problem by adding that path to the PATH environment variable and using a simple "sbcl.exe" in .emacs but in the long term it would be good to know how I can give such a space-containing path to Emacs.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726712/slime-fancy-not-loading-with-emacs-sbcl-slime-windows-configuration), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760868/in-a-emacs-slime-clojure-windows-setup-failure-to-load-clojure-auto), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481910/cannot-start-slime-with-emacs-sbcl-under-windows) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7453668/load-external-with-emacs-slime) did not answer my question.

I tried various syntaxes like

```
;; Setup load-path, autoloads and your lisp system
 (add-to-list 'load-path "d:/slime-2.6")
 (require 'slime-autoloads)
 (setq inferior-lisp-program "\"d:/Program Files/Steel Bank Common Lisp/1.1.12/sbcl.exe\""
```

but I got

```
apply: Searching for program: no such file or directory, "d:/Program
```

What is the correct syntax for Windows paths containing spaces?

Edit: not an answer for the original question but related: one has to add `(slime-setup '(slime-repl))` to `.emacs` in order to start the *slime-repl* subprocess that gives a proper common lisp read-eval-print loop. In the old times it was started automatically but now you should be explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the quotes inside your string, it should be the path, not a string of a string of the path. The spaces will be handled just fine.

`"D:/Program Files/Steel Bank Common Lisp/1.1.12/sbcl.exe"` is how to specify that directory.

You should also look into adding the SBCL directory to your `exec-path` variable. This is just like your PATH, Emacs looks there for executables. Add the directory to your `exec-path` and specify your lisp program as `"sbcl"`

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "d:/slime-2.6")
(require 'slime-autoloads)
(add-to-list 'exec-path "D:/Program Files/Steel Bank Common Lisp/1.1.12/")
(setq inferior-lisp-program "sbcl")
```

Comment: The first suggestion did not work but adding the SBCL path to the exec-path made it work seamlessly, thanks.